# New <style> element not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I currently have an HTML page that has a grey BODY background. Now I would like to overwrite this and change this to white using Javascript. I also would like to change some other elements' padding and margin. I try to accomplish this using the innerHTML property.

The thing is everything is working, apart from the newly introduced  element, which is not applied  in IE7 or IE8. It does work in FireFox however.

```
        <script>
        // if using jQuery
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        document.body.innerHTML = '
    <style type="text/css"> 
      body { 
        background-color: #FFFFFF 
        !important; } 
        #todayBirthdays, #weekendBirthdays, #noBirthdays, #todayJubileums, #weekendJubileums { 
padding: 0 !important; 
        margin: 0 !important; 
        }
    </style>
            <div style="text-align: left; background-color: #FFFFFF">' + 
        document.getElementById('WebPartctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_7118b319_c5b0_4214_a46d_27131866cde3').innerHTML + 
        '</div>';`
                 });
            </script>
```

Can you please advise?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you considered changing the background and other styles you want using the DOM, rather than trying to rebuild the entire document HTML?

Comment: Quite possibly the best line of code I have ever seen -> `document.getElementById('WebPartctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_7118b319_c5b0_4214_a46d_27131866cde3')`

Comment: Gotta love Sharepoint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
$('body').css('background-color', '#fff');
$('#todayBirthdays, #weekendBirthdays, #noBirthdays, #todayJubileums, #weekendJubileums').css('padding', 0).css('margin', 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<style>` tag is only valid inside the `<head>`, though some browsers may respect it in other places. If you want to change the body background or other properties with a script, use the appropriate `.css()` method in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("body")css("backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF");
    $("#todayBirthdays,#weekendBirthdays,#noBirthdays,#todayJubileums,#weekendJubileums").css("margin", "0");
});
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for the feedback. The proper solution was $('body').css('cssText', 'background-color: #ffffff !important'); by the way, since I needed to force the background color!

Answer (score 1):

See the [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) property of jQuery and also the [addclass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method. This is much easier than what you are doing!

```
$('body').css( { backgroundColor: 'value1'  } );
$('#todayBirthdays, #weekendBirthdays, #noBirthdays, #todayJubileums, #weekendJubileums').css( { padding: 'valuex', margin: 'valuey' } );
```

Although I think you should be using addClass instead.

```
.myClass { /* Some styling */ }   

$('#x, #y, #z').addClass(myClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="Text/css">
      body { background-color: #AAA; }
    </stye>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var style = document.createElement('style');

      style.innerHTML = 'body { background-color: #F0F; }';
      // add any other styles inside this style element

      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    </script>
 </body>
```

Demo of appending to the [`<body`>](http://jsfiddle.net/RdNMm/) and the [`<head>`](http://jsfiddle.net/RdNMm/1/)

Comment: _(in case you did want to know how to add a new style tag)_

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck on adding in an inline style which is what you asked then use the following:

```
 $("<style type=\"text/css\"> body{background-color: #FFFFFF;} #todayBirthdays, #weekendBirthdays, #noBirthdays, #todayJubileums, #weekendJubileums { padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;} </style>").appendTo("Head");
```

This will append your styling to the head element of the document. However in reality the better way to go if you are going to use jQuery or javascript is to just change the values of the background.

```
document.getElementByTagName(body).attribute(background-color)="#FFFFFF";
```

OR

```
$("body").css("background-color", "#FFFFF");
```